# What's wrong with this SQL INSERT statement?

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

I want to insert a certain value into a certain field of five different rows altogether. But whenever I run this query it doesn't get executed. What's wrong with it, and how can I fix it?

```
INSERT INTO `employee`(`password`) VALUES ('abc') WHERE `id` IN (1,2,3,4,5);
```

Comment: Are you sure about the `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 4):

An `INSERT` can't have a `WHERE` clause. It looks like you meant to do an update:

```
UPDATE `employee`
SET `password` = 'abc'
WHERE `id` IN (1,2,3,4,5);
```

Or perhaps a multi-row insert:

```
INSERT INTO `employee` (`id`, `password`)
VALUES (1, 'abc'), (2, 'abc'), (3, 'abc'), (4, 'abc'), (5, 'abc');
```

Also, FYI, you *really* shouldn't be storing passwords as plain text, which it looks like you may be doing.

Comment: it is just for experiment purpose ....id is already there,i created a new field called password and want to insert same value to all the rows under those ids

Comment: @AL-zami I'm not sure what you mean, but it sounds like you need the UPDATE example that I posted. If this helped, please remember to select an answer! :)